# UICollectionViewCell size for 3 items per row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a `UICollectionView` with 3 images per row.

For the start i used this code:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(110, 110);
}
```

And it's looking good but it only fits the iPhone X screen:
[image]

Then i tried to use this code so it will put 3 cells per row:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float cellWidth = screenWidth / 3.0;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

    return size;
}
```

But then the view is starting looking different:
[image]

This is the cell initialize method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"TrendingCell";

TrendingCell *cell = (TrendingCell*)[collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

TrendingItem * item = [[[TrendingRep sharedTrending] trendingArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.text.text = item.title;

cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = cell.image.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.image.clipsToBounds = YES;

[cell.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.imageUrl]
               placeholderImage:nil
                        options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                      completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {

                          [cell.progressView setHidden:NO];
}];

return cell;
}
```

Any idea what can be the issue with the view?

Comment: As an option you could IMPL a custom FlowLayout - that, in combination with the usual delegate calls makes it straight forward to size/position each cell.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you're not taking into account the layout's `minimumInteritemSpacing`. The formula to calculate the item's width should be

```
float cellWidth = (screenWidth - 2.0 * minimumInteritemSpacing) / 3.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide minimum spacing between the collection View cell. You
are using collectionviewLayout, So you have to provide minimum spacing like below.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/3 - 10, collectionView.frame.size.width/3)
}
```

Here You can provide minimum spacing (like 10) between cells programmatically.